# Rest webservice

Tags: hibernate, rest, restful-architecture

As part of college assignment, I need to make a restful service for a shopping cart application, with basic functionality like add item, delete item, show all items.

For this, 
the approach discussed in class was using java servlets with Hibernate SessionFactory to handle the cart as the Set with shopping items as the set elements.

Can I do the above without hibernate session?

Comment: yes you can ... you can use plain old JDBC or if you want to go little fancy you can use MyBatis

Comment: this is probably something you should ask your teacher. Basically, on the server side you can do whatever you want - from storing everything into text-files to keeping everything in memory.